# Program runs differently depending on sleep time/pc performance

Tags: java, swing, animation

I want this program to repeat every 15ms and it does work, but if I try it on a slower pc the rendering stops working correctly and only displays about half the screen. I have measured the time it takes to perform one loop and it usually takes 0-3 ms to loop through it, so it should have enough time to do everything and even wait for most of the time to catch up if something is slower. I have tried thread.sleep and wait, but both have the same problem. I have no idea why it performs differently with less time to wait.

```
synchronized (this) {
    LoadMap(LoadedMap);
    //wait(500);
    OldFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (c.running) {
        Objects.RunPhysics();
        Objects.Render();
        if (!Objects.Alive) {
            Objects = Objects.Next;
        }
        renderer.FinishRender();
        //System.out.print(System.currentTimeMillis() - OldFrame + " ");

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - OldFrame < 15) {
            //Thread.sleep(15 - System.currentTimeMillis() + OldFrame);
            //System.out.print(System.currentTimeMillis() - OldFrame + " ");
            wait(15 - System.currentTimeMillis() + OldFrame);
        } else {
            //System.out.print(System.currentTimeMillis() - OldFrame + " ");
            wait(100);
            //Thread.sleep(200);
        }
        OldFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

here are the renderer methods I use. I add the objects and map to an array and save the x and y positions to another array in the render method and then when I want to show it on screen I call the finishrender method, which paints the everything in the array to the screen.

```
public void Render(double posX, double posY, BufferedImage i) {
    image[index] = i;
    ObjectPosX[index] = posX;
    ObjectPosY[index] = posY;
    index++;
    image[index] = null;
}

public void FinishRender() {
    //frame.removeAll();
    //frame.revalidate();
    frame.repaint();
    frame.add(this);
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image[0], 0, 0, (int) Math.round(screenSize.getWidth()), (int) Math.round(screenSize.getHeight()), null);
    for(index = 1; index < image.length - 1 && image[index] != null; index++)
    {
            if(ObjectPosX[index] >= 0){
                g.drawImage(image[index], (int) Math.round((ObjectPosX[index] - 2) * ScreenWidth), (int) Math.round((ActScreenHeight - ((ObjectPosY[index] - 1) * ScreenHeight))), (int) ScreenWidth, (int) ScreenHeight, null);
            } else {
                g.drawImage(image[index], (int) -Math.round((ObjectPosX[index] + 1) * ScreenWidth), (int) Math.round((ActScreenHeight - ((ObjectPosY[index] - 1) * ScreenHeight))), (int) -Math.round(ScreenWidth), (int) Math.round(ScreenHeight), null);
            }
    }
    index = lowestIndex;
}
```

Comment: You're doing several wrong things, including breaking Swing threading rules by making Swing method calls off of the Swing event thread, by re-adding components to a container unnecessarily. Also, no need to repaint the entire JFrame. I have to ask, where did you see this sort of code previously? What tutorial are you using? Whichever it is, it is giving you very bad advice.

Comment: Note that you can find links to the Swing tutorials here, [the Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).

Comment: You should be using `javax.swing.Timer` Your code is difficult to read, [owing to poor naming](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)